# switchMapTo upon source observable emission

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

The difference between `switchMap` and `switchMapTo` is that `switchMap` transforms each source emission into observable upon the emission and `switchMapTo` ignores emitted value and transforms each emission to an Observable that is built up during *stream creation*.

The thumb rule here is use `switchMap` when your inner stream depends on the source stream values and use `switchMapTo` when it doesn't.

But what if I don't care for the emission value but I do care for the emission time?
Meaning I'd like the inner Observable to be evaluated upon source Observable emission.

The obvious thing here is to use `switchMap(() => Observable)` but it just doesn't feel right, because of the thumb rule I mentioned before.

---

**Example with `switchMapTo` (*bad*):**

```js
const predefinedKey = 'key';

//This need to be initialized
const obj = {};

function getObservable(key){
  return Rx.Observable.of(obj[key]);
}

//This is initialization stream
const initialize = new Rx.ReplaySubject();
initialize.next(1);

const onInit = initialize.do(val => obj[predefinedKey] = val);

//Would like to access the object only after initialization
const result = onInit.switchMapTo(getObservable(predefinedKey));
//Expect to see 1 in output but see 'undefined' because switchMapTo evaluated before the object is initialized
result.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

**Example with `switchMap` (*good*):**

```js
const predefinedKey = 'key';

//This need to be initialized
const obj = {};

function getObservable(key){
  return Rx.Observable.of(obj[key]);
}

//This is initialization stream
const initialize = new Rx.ReplaySubject();
initialize.next(1);

const onInit = initialize.do(val => obj[predefinedKey] = val);

//Would like to access the object only after initialization
const result = onInit.switchMap(() => getObservable(predefinedKey));
//Expect to see 1 in output
result.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

The examples are very artificial but they describe the situation pretty well.

What is the right approach here? Any other Observable function I can use for delayed execution?

Comment: I don't see reason it's not right thing. I also have quite similar pattern quite frequently around `mergeMap` or `map` operators that indicate it only depends on source emission but drops off those values then map into completely another one instead.

Comment: »But what if I don't care for the emission value but I do care for the emission time?« Can you show an example for this situation?

Comment: Provided example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example, you can use `switchMapTo` in combination with `Observable.defer`:

```js
const predefinedKey = 'key';
const obj = {};

function getObservable(key){
  return Rx.Observable.defer(() => Rx.Observable.of(obj[key]));
}

const initialize = new Rx.ReplaySubject();
initialize.next(1);

const onInit = initialize.do(val => obj[predefinedKey] = val);

const result = onInit.switchMapTo(getObservable(predefinedKey));
result.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of deferring in `getObservable`, you could also defer in the `switchMapTo` call:

```
const result = onInit.switchMapTo(Rx.Observable.defer(() => getObservable(predefinedKey)));
```

This will just depend on the situation. That said, I also don't think there's anything wrong with using `switchMap` and personally, I'd probably do that instead of deferring (which is useful in other situations).